# Use mandatory profiles on the RD Session Host server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, profile

I want to configure my Windows Server 2008 servers like this. A user logs on, they load a profile that has been configured for that server and no changes can be made to the profile.

I want to do this is with a mandatory profile, and 2 policies: "Use mandatory profiles on the RD Session Host server" and "Set path for Remote Desktop Services User Profile"

So for each server, I log on, create a profile, save it as a mandatory profile, enable both policies, and in "Set path for Remote Desktop Services User Profile" I set the path to the previously saved mandatory profile.

I've tested this, and it doesn't work. When I log on to the server using RDP, it loads the local default profile. When I log off it saves the profile in the usual location, C:\Users, and I can make changes which are then saved to the profile. It's as if the policy setting hasn't been applied, but when I view rsop I can see that the policy IS applied. There are no errors when logging on or in event viewer.

Can anyone offer any ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Possible errors you made or missed

1. The profile must be allowed to read by `Authenticated Users` (Apply file security reucrsively to profile folder)
2. The profile folder must be named `C:\Users\MandatoryUser.V2` ( and the `Set path for Remote Desktop Services User Profile` must be `C:\Users\MandatoryUser` without `.V2` for Windows Server 2008 and higher.
3. `MandatoryUser` is just an example username.
4. You must open RegEdit and Load Mandatory user's ntuser.dat file into (Click `HKEY_USERS`, Click `File-Load Hive`)， then set security on loaded hive to `Authenticated Users`:`Full Control`
5. You must rename mandatory user `ntuser.dat` to `ntuser.man`
6. **(!)** You need to delete users who previously logged on to server before let them use mandatory profile: delete `c:\users\username`， delete them from registry ( Delete hive `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<user's SID>`. Here you can look through all hives to find `ProfileImagePath` that corresponds to your user)
7. The mandatory profile is recreated when user makes LogOn! When user is logged on，and after user logs off, it acts like a normal profile.
8. In `System Properties\Advanced\User Profiles` mandatory profiles are marked as Mandatory.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180814100202/https://markswinkels.nl/2009/12/how-to-create-a-mandatory-profile-in-windows-server-2008-r2/) is one of the best guides about mandatory profiles. It has some security issues, but as a beginning is very good

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I went through the process again just to check I haven't missed anything, it's basically what I did to start with. Unfortunately it still doesn't load my mandatory profile - it logs me on with the default local profile again. 

Just a couple of things to clarify...
1. I loaded the file NTUSER.dat to the hive, and gave permissions Authenticated Users - Full Control. Is that right - or should I rename to NTUSER.man, then load that into the registry hive and assign it permissions?
2. I unloaded the hive after I assigned permissions - is that right?

Comment: 3. "Set path for Remote Desktop Services User Profile" conatins a link to a share - \\MyComputerName\UsersFolder\TSProfile (actual folder is D:\UsersFolder\TSProfile.V2) - does it make a difference whether I enter \\MyComputerName\UsersFolder\TSProfile or D:\UsersFolder\TSProfile?

Comment: After going through the process again System Properties\Advanced\User Profiles shows my profile as local

Comment: Did you deleted your profile before try-again? From registry?

Comment: Yes, and I know it isn't re-loading the same profile again because I made some changes, and those changes are gone - I just get the default local profile